# Show Material UI GridsV2 one below the other

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm trying to display two GridsV2 one below the other using MaterialDesign for React. Unfortunately this is not possible. They are always displayed side by side.
Even if I'm using the first Grid version
Even if I use the grid version 1 this problem remains

```
import Grid2 from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2";

<Grid container style={{ marginTop: "5%" }} justifyContent={"center"}>
    <Grid2 item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
    <Divider></Divider>
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="column">
      <h3 justifyContent="center" alignContent={"center"}>
        Wurde Ihnen schon mal durch eigenes Verschulden ein Mietverhältnis gekündigt
      </h3>

      <Stack direction="row" justifyContent={"center"}>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={question1 === "ja"}
              onChange={() => setQuestion1("ja")}
            />
          }
          label="Ja"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={question1 === "nein"}
              onChange={() => setQuestion1("nein")}
            />
          }
          label="Nein"
        />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  </Grid2>

  <Grid2 item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
    <Divider></Divider>
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="column">
      <h3 justifyContent="center" alignContent={"center"}>
        Haben Sie aktuell eine Anstellung mit unbefristetem Arbeitsvertrag
      </h3>

      <Stack direction="row" justifyContent={"center"}>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={question1 === "ja"}
              onChange={() => setQuestion1("ja")}
            />
          }
          label="Ja"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={question1 === "nein"}
              onChange={() => setQuestion1("nein")}
            />
          }
          label="Nein"
        />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  </Grid2>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the container `Grid` could set `direction="column"` and `alignItems="center"` to place the children `Grid2` one after another, and center them horizontally.

Tested the simplified example here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qhmudj?file=src/App.js)

Example:

```
<Grid
  container
  //  Add these
  direction="column"
  alignItems="center"
  style={{ marginTop: "5%" }}
>
  <Grid2 item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
    <Divider></Divider>
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="column">
      <h3 justifyContent="center" alignContent={"center"}>
        Wurde Ihnen schon mal durch eigenes Verschulden ein Mietverhältnis
        gekündigt
      </h3>
      <Stack direction="row" justifyContent={"center"}>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
             checked={question1 === 'ja'}
             onChange={() => setQuestion1('ja')}
            />
          }
          label="Ja"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
             checked={question1 === 'nein'}
             onChange={() => setQuestion1('nein')}
            />
          }
          label="Nein"
        />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  </Grid2>
  <Grid2 item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
    <Divider></Divider>
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="column">
      <h3 justifyContent="center" alignContent={"center"}>
        Haben Sie aktuell eine Anstellung mit unbefristetem Arbeitsvertrag
      </h3>

      <Stack direction="row" justifyContent={"center"}>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
             checked={question1 === 'ja'}
             onChange={() => setQuestion1('ja')}
            />
          }
          label="Ja"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
             checked={question1 === 'nein'}
             onChange={() => setQuestion1('nein')}
            />
          }
          label="Nein"
        />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  </Grid2>
</Grid>
```